# "URL key for specified store already exists" for category when importing products

Tags: magento2, import

The categories the products needs to be imported to are already created. When I try to import the products I get this error:

```
1. Category "Default Category/Accessories/Mobil Sleeves" has not been created. URL key for specified store already exists. in row(s): 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41
```

Row 32, column `categories` content:

```
Default Category/Accessories/Mobil Sleeves,Default Category/Mærker/Accessories/Decadent,Default Category/Accessories,Default Category/Udsalg,Default Category/Accessories/UDSALG Accessories
```

- All products has unique a `url_key`
- Category name is `Mobil Sleeves`. Full category path is: `Default Category/Accessories/Mobil Sleeves`
- Category `url_key`: `mobil-sleeves`
- in the table `url_rewrite`only one instance exists for the category: `accessories/mobil-sleeves.html`
- I use Magento 2.1.2

Comment: `url_key` is a Unique Key. So u can't use same URL. U can use like `mobil-sleeves-1` or any other but not same

Comment: Use different product names for each product.

Comment: As I said no products has the url_key mobil-sleeves. Also there is no products with duplicate names or url_key.

Answer (score 1):

When name of product is same at that time this error come. Magento 2 automatically generate url key based on name but if name same then gives same key error.

Please check name of product if its same for two products the try to add unique key for both product

Answer (score 0):

Check the 'url_key' column in the csv file there u definitely see duplicate url keys. when the error shows like: URL key for specified store already exists. in row(s): 32 , then we have to check the 33rd row because 1st row heading(eg : product_type, category etc..)magento will add that also. so when ever it show a row error add 1 and check that row. what i did was deleted those entire row.

Comment: I did account for the first row being headers. When I say row 32 I technically mean row 33. I have check again and all url_key are unique and no products has mobil-sleeves.

Comment: The solution posted by Rahul worked for me. Something else you should take into account is that if your products have very similar names, they can have a url_key that is generated as the same, i.e if your products are: "black motorcycle jacket with cobra design" and "black motorcycle jacket with chicken design" the url_key generated might be the same for both, hence this problem. Hope this helps.